# WP Admin - blocked or unsupported cookies

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, error-handling

[when attempting to login using the correct Username and Password combination, I see this error message thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQogA.png)

what should be done?

We haven't had much luck fixing this error yet. Need to knom what can be done to fix iut..

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable your security and cache plugins. You can do this through FTP. Open FTP follow this path:

wp-content/plugins/your-security-plugins

rename your security plugins and then they will be automatically deactivated. If your issue is still not solving then try to permanently block the cookies.
Open your theme's functions.php file and add this code:

```
setcookie(TEST_COOKIE, 'WP Cookie check', 0, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
if ( SITECOOKIEPATH != COOKIEPATH ) setcookie(TEST_COOKIE, 'WP Cookie check', 0, SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
```

Save the file and refresh your WordPress.
Hope this will help you.